# Different ways of implementing Factory Method Pattern

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I saw a `Factory Method Pattern` example, in which the Client class is defined as abstract class and includes an abstract method (i.e. the factory method) that is something like this:

```
abstract createCourse(String scheduleType);
```

So, I need to extend the abstract Client class and implement the `createCourse` method. Below an example that represents the Client:

```
public abstract class CourseProvider {
    public Course startCourse(String scheduleType){
        Course course = createCourse(scheduleType);         
        course.setAvailability(true);

        return course;
    }

    abstract createCourse(String scheduleType); 
}
```

Each time I want to use a different factory I have to extend it.

However, I found another way for implementing this pattern, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492900/From-No-Factory-to-Factory-Method). In that article the abstract factory method is not defined inside the client (it is not more abstract: may be abstract, but it is not required), but it is defined inside another class that represents the base class for the Factory.

```
public abstract class AbstractCourseFactory
{
    publicAbstractCourse createCourse(String scheduleType)
    {
        Course objCourse = this.getCourse(ScheduleType);        
        objCourse.createCourseMaterial();
        objCourse.createSchedule();
        return objCourse;
    }
    public abstract Course getCourse(String scheduleType);
}
```

So each time I want define a different Factory, I just need to extend this base class, and implement the factory method. And then the Client should have a reference to the Factory base class (AbstractCourseFactory).

So now my Client class should look like this:

```
public class CourseProvider {
    AbstractCourseFactory factory;

    public CourseProvider(AbstractCourseFactory factory){
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public Course startCourse(String scheduleType){
        Course course = factory.getCourse();
        course.start();
    }
}
```

But this implementation of the Client class (CourseProvider) seems to be a `"Simple Factory Pattern"`.

So, is the last way of implementing the Factory Method Pattern right? Which is the most correct?

Comment: It seems like the second example is an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), not just a Factory Method.

Comment: Also, the first rule of Abstract Factory is "try not to use Abstract Factory". The `scheduleType` argument in your creational method denotes potential misusage of Factory. The concrete type of the Factory should determine which type of object is created, not parameters passed to the creation method.

Comment: Thank you @guillaume31, but this article [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492900/From-No-Factory-to-Factory-Method#Index) says that it is a Factory Method Pattern, not an Abstract Factory Pattern. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're not, the article is (or at least, inaccurate) :)

Comment: Maybe :) However, from the best of my knowledge, the two patterns are very similar, and the only difference is that the Abstract Pattern emphasizes the aspect of grouping in families.

Comment: Another difference is that a Factory Method is just a method in any object, while the Abstract Factory involves a dedicated creational class.

Comment: This is the main difference between your 2 code samples and therefore, I think, an answer to the very question you asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Both are Factory Patterns. They are used in different occasions.

The first one is used when there are one type of classes.
The second one gives an interface for creating a family of classes.

Since the doubt is on 2nd implementation, i will try to explain it in detail..

Please see that the following class has an abstract method `getCourse`

```
public abstract class AbstractCourseFactory
{
    publicAbstractCourse createCourse(String scheduleType)
    {
        Course objCourse = this.getCourse(ScheduleType);        
        objCourse.createCourseMaterial();
        objCourse.createSchedule();
        return objCourse;
    }
    public abstract Course getCourse(String scheduleType);
}
```

The getCourse is the actual creator of the course object. While the createCourse simply does some set up of the created object.

So users have to create multiple factory classes based on this and return the appropriate concrete Course object. Each Factory Class will be specific for a family of classes.

Also please note that usually, Course is an interface or abstract class.
Lets say we have two family of courses.. GradedCourse and NonGradedCourses

```
interface Course {
   public String getCourseName();
}

public abstract class GradedCourse implements Course {
... 
}


GradedCourseA extends GradedCourse {
...
}

GradedCourseB extends GradedCourse {
...
}

public abstract class NonGradedCourse implements Course {
... 
}

NonGradedCourseA extends NonGradedCourse {
...
}

NonGradedCourseB extends NonGradedCourse {
...
}
```

The AbsctractCourseFactory would be extended to create two classes as below

```
public CourseFactoryGradedCourses extends AbsctractCourseFactory {
   public Course getCourse(String scheduleType) {
      if (scheduleType.equals("A") {
         return new GradedCourseA ();
      } else if (scheduleType.equals("B") {
         return new GradedCourseB ();
      }
   }
}

public CourseFactoryNonGradedCourses extends AbsctractCourseFactory {
   public Course getCourse(String scheduleType) {
      if (scheduleType.equals("A") {
         return new NonGradedCourseA ();
      } else if (scheduleType.equals("B") {
         return new NonGradedCourseB ();
      }
   }
}
```

So the CourseProvider  would be supplied with appropriate concrete factory implementation so that classes from that family are created.

```
...
 CourseProvider gradedCourseProvider= CourseProvider (new CourseFactoryGradedCourses ());
  // -->This creates concrete class GradedCourseA  from the family of graded courses..
  gradedProvider.startCourse("A");

 CourseProvider nonGradedCourseProvider =  CourseProvider (new CourseFactoryNonGradedCourses ());
     // -->This creates concrete class NonGradedCourseA  from the family of non graded courses..
  nonGradedCourseProvider.startCourse("A");
```

Both are correct Factory patterns. 
The second one is used when there are different families of classes that need to be created.

The patterns are explained neatly in "Head First Design pattens" book.

Comment: Thank you! I have take the first example from Head First Design Patterns, while the second one is taken from [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492900/From-No-Factory-to-Factory-Method#Index). In the latter the implementation of the Creator calss coincides with the "Simple Factory Pattern" described in the Head First book

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement a factory method something like this:

```
public void DoSomething(Func<Stream> streamFactory)
{
    using(var stream = streamFactory())
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(..))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
DoSomething(() => new FileStream(...));
```

Note: I realise the example of a `Stream` has nothing to do with the example in the question, but the question IS about different ways of implementing a factory method.